# Inheritance and Exception Handling

Tags: c#, inheritance, exception

I am trying to complete a homework assignment however I am not sure what to do next. I have been struggling with Inheritance and Exception Handling...this problem combines the two.
Could you please give me a shove in the right direction?

Here is the question:
Create a program named BookExceptionDemo for the Peterman Publishing Company. The company has decided that no published book should cost more than 10 cents per page. Create a BookException class whose constructor requires three arguments: a string Book title, a double price, and an int number of pages. Create an error message that is passed to the Exception class constructor for the Message property when a book does not meet the price-to-page ratio. For example, an error message might be:

For Goodnight Moon, ratio is invalid.
...Price is $12.99 for 25 pages.

Create a Book class that contains fields for title, author, price, and number of pages. Include properties for each field. throw a BookException if a client program tries to construct a Book object for which the price is more than 10 cents per page. Create a program that creates at least four Book objects - some where the ratio is acceptable and others where it is not. Catch any thrown exceptions and display the BookException Message.

Here is what I have so far:

```
namespace BookExceptionDemo
{
    class BookException : Exception
    {
        public BookException(string title, double price, int numberPages)
             : base("For " + title + ", ratio is invalid. \nPrice is $" + price + " for " + numberPages + " pages.") //p.470
        {
        }
    }

    class Book
    {
        public Book(string title, double price, int numberPages)  //he said this should check to see if the ratio is correct, if not, then throw exception.
        { 
        }

        public string Title { get; private set; }

        public double Price { get; private set; }

        public int NumberPages { get; private set; }
    }

    // my teacher put this here
    // but at the end of class he said the contents should be moved somewhere else?
    // Does it go in the BookException constructor? 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                throw (new BookException("Goodnight Moon", 12.99, 25));
            }
            catch (BookException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.Read();
       }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
My school switched programming languages this semester, so I came into this intermediate C# course with no prior knowledge of the language. I understood most things up until the past few class sessions. I was getting frustrated in my confusion and was feeling disheartened, but now I can honestly say that I am excited to have a better understanding of these concepts. Programming is really fun and I really appreciate people like you who are willing to help others. Thank you all for the time and effort you have given in assisting me.

Here is what I believe to be the correct answer to the question I posted.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BookExceptionDemo
{
    class BookException : Exception
    {
        public BookException(string title, double price, int numberPages)
            : base("For " + title + ", ratio is invalid. \nPrice is $" + price + " for " + numberPages + " pages.")
        {

        }
    }

    class Book
    {
        public Book(string title, string author, double price, int numberPages)
        {
            if ((price / numberPages) > .1)
            {
                throw new BookException(title, price, numberPages);
            }
        }

        private string title;
        private string author;
        private double price;
        private int numberPages;


        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return title;
            }
            set 
            {
                title = value;
            }
        }

        public string Author
        {
            get
            {
                return author;
            }
            set
            {
                author = value;
            }
        }

        public double Price
        {
            get
            {
                return price;
            }
            set
            {
                price = value;
            }
        }

        public int NumberPages
        {
            get
            {
                return numberPages;
            }
            set
            {
                numberPages = value;
            }
        }

    }

    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Book junglebook = new Book("Jungle Book","Kipling", 25.99, 50);   //should throw exception
            }
            catch (BookException ex)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            try
            {
                Book hobbit = new Book("The Hobbit","Tolkien", 2.99, 30);   //should NOT throw exception
            }
            catch (BookException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            try
            {
                Book book1984 = new Book("1984","Orwell", 31.32, 15);   //should throw exception
            }
            catch (BookException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            try
            {
                Book guidetonetworks = new Book("Guide to Networks","Somebody", 17.56, 500);   //should NOT throw exception
            }
            catch (BookException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you are actually asking? You *almost* have it. Also; I'm not sure deriving from Exception counts as "using" inheritance (ok fine, you inherited, but its not like you are really utilizing polymorphism).

Comment: If you are specializing your exception to take a title, price and numberPages, why don't you just pass the book itself to the constructor of the exception?

Comment: @bash0r Because that would be *way* too confusing ;) Good advice for production code though

Comment: I guess this is what you want to do next: `create at least four Book objects - some where the ratio is acceptable and others where it is not.`, do you understand how to create a Book object?

Comment: @ekad He needs to get his `throw` in the right place first

Comment: I just don't really know where to go from here. I don't understand where I should place the sample code (provided by my instructor in the Program class). Also, one of the things I have been struggling with is understanding how the program knows when to throw the exception.  To sum up my issue, I seem to be able to set up the classes and constructors, but I don't understand how they should be "linked".

Comment: @Ranger133 do you know when the `Book` constructor will be executed?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yes I realized that, I just want to know if he understands how constructor works first, he *might* not know that yet.

Comment: @ekad It should be executed each time a new book is initiated right?

Comment: Correct. Constructors are invoked on instantiation.

Comment: @Ranger133 Yes, that's a start :) so now you can check if the ratio is acceptable inside the `Book` constructor, in this case it's not acceptable when the book costs more than 10 cents per page. If it's not acceptable, then throw a `BookException`.

Comment: @ekad So when I instantiate a new object its properties are transferred to the class for that type of object? And the constraints for exceptions related to that class should be included inside the constructors for that class?

Comment: @Ranger133 Yes you are correct, the point of checking the constraints inside the constructor is to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Generally speaking, I would avoid exceptions in constructors, but thats just me. Its fine because its an assignment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of exceptions is that something *really* bad has happened. **So bad** that you are interrupting the control flow of the program.

In this case, you need to throw as (effectively) a validation step when creating a book. The check needs to happen on book creation, so we put it in the constructor:

```
public Book(string title, double price, int numberPages)
{ 
    bool goodPrice = true; //Actual condition left as an exercise
    if (!goodPrice) //No good, bail!
        throw new BookException(title, price, numberPages);
}
```

The calling code will need to wrap any invocations of `Book`s constructor in a `try/catch` to handle this. Be aware that a thrown exception breaks normal control flow, the catch block is immediately entered and control is not returned to the try block.

The `Program` class and indeed all these classes, typically reside in their own files, which is possibly what your instructor was alluding to by saying it would normally be somewhere else.

Regardless, you already know how to invoke a constructor (through instantiation, you did it for the exception!). Now you just need to create a few `Book` objects (some with invalid parameters). With the code given, the `Main` method makes sense for this.

A sample call would look like:

```
try
{
   Book introToC = new Book("C# is Awesome!", 10.00, 100);
}
catch (BookException ex) //Specify what we are catching!
{
   //Do something, in your case print. (Left as exercise).
}
```

**Update**

To your question about why we use `try/catch`. First, I suggest you ask your instructor, as he will explain it better than I can :).

However, try to imagine your objects as *actual objects* and it makes a bit more sense. Suppose I had a "SuperBigButton" class with a "Click" method. In real terms, its a super big button I can push.

Suppose I then push that button, but I forgot to turn it on (I'm not terribly bright in this example). Now, the thing attached to the button *could* just print out an error message, or even do nothing, but the point is *I don't know anything is wrong*.

It is better if it punches me in the face, saying "You didn't turn it on!". This is *much* more useful to me (the calling code). Certainly there are patterns where `bool` return values are used instead of exceptions (the `TryParse` family of functions come to mind) but this is why we use exceptions. We need to be able to "error out" and tell the calling code something is broken.

Exceptions also have the advantage of interrupting the control flow, so anything in the calling code that depended on the given call succeeding will not run (they are skipped as control moves to the `catch` block).

Comment: Thank you very much Bradley! This stuff just wasn't really making sense in class. I asked my instructor for help, but his English is not great... he didn't really understand my question  and then I didn't really understand his response.  However, I think I understand now. So to clarify, with just an exception (no try/catch) the program simply stops and the user does not know why. But we use try/catch blocks so that when an exception occurs a specific message is displayed to the user; is that correct?

Comment: @Ranger133 From a very simplistic perspective, yes, that is correct. An *unhandled* exception (no try/catch) will bubble up through the call stack until it hits the runtime, which will then terminate the program. A `catch` statement can do many things besides notify the user, but that certainly is *one* thing you can do. Just trying to make sure you don't have misconceptions later. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it is all making sense now. Thank you very much for your help! I am very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

```
public Book(string title, double price, int numberPages)
{
   if(price / numberPages > 0.1)
      throw new BookException(title, price, numberPages);
}
```

Comment: I can appreciate not just giving the code. Is this really an answer though?

Comment: i showed him where to put the code - he was asking that

Comment: Without actually giving any code, would this question ever actually have an answer to your expectation?